# Email from Case - Unable to find default record type

Tags: email, case, record-type

One of our users is receiving the following error message when attempting to send an email from a case he is the owner of. Our other users are not encountering this issue. After reviewing his profile and permissions, I've not found anything missing. His profile seems to have access to everything necessary for sending an email from a case. Debugging around his user while reproducing the error didn't turn up anything either. I've included a screenshot of the debug logs from recreating the error as his user further below.

Does anyone know why a user would be encountering this error message while sending an email from a case they own?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any record type on task object ?

Comment: We have Enhanced Email enabled. Here's the Enhanced Email description in SFDC: 


"Enhanced Email elevates email to a standard Salesforce object, with customization options and an API. Emails are no longer stored as tasks, but as full-featured records, complete with details, related lists, and collaboration tools. On email records, users can view their messages exactly as their customers do, complete with formatting."

Comment: Ok but can you still confirm that there is no record type on task? I see your point, but it could happen that task is still created and if record type exist, the user profile may not have any default record type set on task. It might be worth checking

Comment: You were correct! It was an issue with Task record types. Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: Great. I've added an answer to summarise how to resolve the issue, could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, 'Send Email' feature is linked to Task object. 
Task object had record type and no default record type was assigned to that user profile.
Assigning the default Task record type to the profile will resolve the issue